# Jquery slideUp not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

Hey guys I'm trying to create a view with an accordion using this HTML:

```
<ul class="left_menu_list">
  <li class="left_menu_item active" data-item="firma">
    <div>LA FIRMA</div>
    <ul class="firma_list secondary_list">
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA firma_list</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="left_menu_item" data-item="areas">
    <div>ÁREAS E INDUSTRIAS</div>
    <ul class="areas_list hidden secondary_list">
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA areas_list</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="left_menu_item" data-item="oficinas">
    <div>OFICINAS</div>
    <ul class="oficinas_list hidden secondary_list">
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA oficinas_list</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="left_menu_item" data-item="equipo">
    <div>EQUIPO</div>
    <ul class="equipo_list hidden secondary_list">
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA equipo_list</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="left_menu_item" data-item="compromiso">
    <div>COMPROMISO</div>
    <ul class="compromiso_list hidden secondary_list">
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA compromiso_list</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="left_menu_item" data-item="comunicacion">
    <div>COMUNICACIÓN</div>
    <ul class="comunicacion_list hidden secondary_list">
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA comunicacion_list</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="left_menu_item" data-item="empleo">
    <div>EMPLEO</div>
    <ul class="empleo_list hidden secondary_list">
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA empleo_list</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="left_menu_item" data-item="alumni">
    <div>ALUMNI</div>
    <ul class="alumni_list hidden secondary_list">
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA empleo_list</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
      <li class="secondary_list_item">LA FIRMA</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With this css:

```
.left_menu_list{
        .left_menu_item{
          .secondary_list{
            display: none;
            position: relative;
            background: @white;
            margin-top: 0;
            left: -4.42vw;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            padding-left: 4.42vw;
            .secondary_list_item{
              margin-left: 20px;
            }
          }
}
```

I've create some JS code, trying to create the effect:

```
$('.left_menu_item').click(function(){
   if(false == $(this).children('ul').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).children('ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

The main problem is that slideDown() effect works perfectly but, the slideUp() one does not works. It makes the slide down, but when I click on another item, the slideUp does not trigger, it just get hiden with no effect.

Does anyone know why?
Thanks.

Comment: can you try to simple toggle the slide?

So using slideToggle() instead of slideDown() slideUp()

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. The `if`  condition never evaluates to true, resulting in always calling `slideToggle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Do it like below (only 3 line of code):-***

```
$('.left_menu_item').click(function(){
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
  $('.left_menu_item').not(this).children('ul').slideUp();
});
```

***Note:-*** `CSS` shown by you is wrong. Change it accordingly as i do in my answer

Also you can provide some time-span in both like `slideToggle(500)` and `slideUp(500)` to make it bit smother.

***Working example with your code:-***

https://jsfiddle.net/b8ww8q8L

Answer (score 0):

hello use the below code

```
$(".left_menu_list > li > div").click(function(){
if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
    $('.left_menu_list ul').slideUp(300);
}
$(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
$('.left_menu_list ul:eq(0)').show();
```

see the below fiddle

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/d5WzS/111/)